# What am i doing wrong here(dynamics)?they should give the same answer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

So a body $m$ is on a uniform circular motion ($\omega = d\theta/dt = \text{constant}$), it is suspended by an inextensible rope with negligeable mass:

[image]

First picture

so:

$$ -mg + T \cos \alpha = 0 $$

and:

$$ -mRw^2 = -T\sin \alpha $$

this gives:

$$ \alpha = \arccos\left(\frac{g}{lw^2}\right) $$

So this is what the book did.

What I did I drew the same diagram on another way so I an use polar coordinates (second picture).

So the Weight is perpendicular to the vector $r$ and $\theta$, this is a problem since we won't have $mg$ in our equation at the end like the reasoning with the other picture but lets continue.

On $r$:

$$ - T \sin \alpha = -rw^2 $$

on $\theta$:

$$ -T \cos \alpha = 0 $$

And this is wrong.

I've been confused for 3 days in a row , what am I doing wrong?

EDIT Second picture is he same system but from uppoint of view , it gives me diffrent results

Comment: This question is not really clear to me. What is your second picture of? What is it you are trying to solve?

Comment: So basically you are solving two different problems, getting two different answers, and wondering why you are getting two different answers?

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn't help to look at the system from above. I suggest you draw a free-body diagram from the side-view like:

[image]

Since there is no acceleration in the y-direction you know the vertical tension component cancels the gravitational force, which gives you $T\cos\alpha = mg$. The horizontal component is what provides the centripetal force towards the center of the plane of oscillation $T\sin\alpha = mR\omega^2$, where $R$ is related to the given length $l$ by $R=l\sin\alpha$.